# Resizing photo on a canvas without losing the aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, image, css, resize, html5-canvas

Hi all thanks for any help in advance.  I am writing a phonegap app and can not get the photo to shrink without either losing the aspect or cropping the image by mistake.  In the function below "imageData" is a 64bit string of the photo that the camera took.  I can draw the image onto the canvas on my page, but if the picture was taken in landscape then it is smashed together.  If i do not scale it either by using the scale function or the drawimage function then i get only the top corner of the photo.  A example: i took a photo the image width in the onPhotoDataSuccess function shows it to be 1296px wide, and 968px height.  But my canvas on the iPhone is 272px wide (portrait mode).  I have tried many different scaling methods on the web and this appears to be the closest by not quite.  What am i doing wrong?

```
 function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) 
{
var myImage = new Image();
var thecanvas = document.getElementById("queImg");
var ctx = thecanvas.getContext("2d"); 
myImage.onload = function() 
  { 
    thecanvas.setAttribute('width', '100%');
    thecanvas.setAttribute('height', 'auto');
    ctx.scale((myImage.width * 0.15), (myImage.height * 0.15));  
    ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);   
    }     

    myImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;      
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scaling is built in to drawImage.

Don't use setAttribute when dealing with canvas, call `canvas.width = 272` instead, and only with whole pixel values.

Here is some working code to get you started:

```
 function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData)
{
var myImage = new Image();
var thecanvas = document.getElementById("queImg");
var ctx = thecanvas.getContext("2d");

    myImage.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, myImage.width * 0.15, myImage.height * 0.15);
    }     

    myImage.src = "http://placekitten.com/1296/968";
}


onPhotoDataSuccess(null);
```

Live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QBTrg/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can just draw like this, without the `scale` function:

```
ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, myImage.width * 0.15, myImage.height * 0.15);
```

However, the resolution has to be set explicitly, not in terms of percentages. E.g.:

```
window.onload = function() {
    thecanvas.width = window.width;
    thecanvas.height = window.height;
}
```