# Image width and height without stretching or overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get an image with unknown height and width to fit inside of a div with 300px width and 300px height.  I always need to see the entire image.

**Example 1**: Image that comes in with **300px height** and **200px width**, will result in **100% height** and **66% width** of it's parent div

**Example 2**: Image that comes in with **200px height** and **300px width**, will result in **66% height** and **100% width** of it's parent div

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resizing photo on a canvas without losing the aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752366/resizing-photo-on-a-canvas-without-losing-the-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the image as the background-image of the div you can use the css style

```
background-size: contain;
```

Here's a jsfiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/04y4dm06/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this but I think you can ask it with jQuery:

```
if($('incoming_pic').css('height') > '300px'){
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.your_block img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```