# jQuery mobile Upload Image later when Internet is good

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm building a mobile web application using JQuery Mobile. I have done image upload in the application where, I access Mobile Camera to take picture and upload.

My Problem is when I upload image, If my internet is not good I loss the Images which I am uploading.

**Code:**

```
<form id="uploadimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" data-clear-btn="false" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" capture>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
</form>
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way I can upload image later when the Internet connection is good.?
2. Is there a way to save the image by creating a folder and upload from it later?
3. How can I check the Internet strength using "jQuery mobile" and prompt the user with low internet, so he/she can upload later!

Or

Is there any other way to solve it?

**Note:**

- My Application was accessed through "Browser" so I know that i was limited to access the folders.
- Please, dont advice me to create a APP, So i can achieve my solution. Because I already have a APP which dose this. But few of my users need web application.

Answer (score 1):

Its only an idea :

1) You can start a timeout when you try to upload a file :

```
  var uploadTimeout= window.setTimeout( function() {
        alert( "upload is slow" );
        // cancel upload and save in temp folder here
    }, 1000 );

   $(document).on( 'load', function() {
        window.clearTimeout( uploadTimeout);
    }, false );
```

2) If it crash or reach the timeout you can use client local storage to store files on the client side :  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

3) While there are some files in the localStorage retry to upload them.

Comment: Do you think that.. We can access files from temp folder?

Comment: can the local storage hold the images? I read the link of html5_webstorage.. But as u know that a single image in Samsung or IOS size vary from 4-5MB but My application have to store more then that.. but HTML5 can store 5Mb but data alone?

Comment: You are right Html5 storage is limited to 10MB per origin (in chrome). You should compress pic on the client side before saving. On our apps we are playing with a canvas before uploading. (something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6752580/5703316)