# How to maintain image aspect ratio and make sure it fits inside the container?

Tags: css, sass, responsive-design, less, responsive-images

I have been struggling with this problem for a couple of weeks now. I have a container which is 90vh. I have some header text and below it is an image. I need to maintain the aspect ratio of 16:9. But, the height must never exceed the height of the container causing scrollbar to appear. Is it doable??

Here is the calculation for 16:9 aspect ratio

To get height base on width
(9 * WIDTH) / 16;

To get width base on height
(16 * HEIGHT) / 9

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-sara-ew3oj9?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 2):

the `.wrapper` element never exceed the height of the container, because `90vh` isn't working.

❌ the part which is wrong

```css
height: "90vh"; /* turn this from string to number, without this "" */
```

✅ make it like this:

```css
height: 90vh;
```

---

also for the aspect-ratio problem,

you can a native css solution, called [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio)

```css
img {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  width: 100%;
}
```

> with this solution, the image will be always 100%,
>
>  but the height change depends on aspect-ratio

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 80% 20%;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 90vh;
  /* turn this from string to number, without this "" */
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.content img {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Here is header</h1>
        <p>Here is sub header</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <img alt="Hello" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611771341253-dadb347165a8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OHx8YmVhdXRpZnVsJTIwbmF0dXJlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" />
        <div class="sidebar">Side bar</div>
      </div>
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <!-- container -->
  </div>
  <!-- wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- app -->
```

Comment: I am using canvas. And the image is inside canvas. So, we can't use css style for the image. Is there any other ways??

Comment: @NyiNyiHmueAung yes, you need javascript for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/29676404/17716837 (in the question you asked for an img tag, not canvas)

Comment: here a useful documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images

Comment: or use this: "Resizing photo on a canvas without losing the aspect ratio" https://stackoverflow.com/a/6752580/17716837

Answer (score 0):

Set max-width on your image, to force it to take the size of the grid you defined. Also set a height 100% on your `.container` class

```
 img {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
```